# Linked list- find_node_data

Tags: c, struct, binary-search-tree

I have previously posted about this same topic. I am self-learning data structures using MIT Open Courseware. I'm doing the **6.S096-Introduction to C/C++ course** and attempting the fourth assignment.

It is based on **binary search trees** and I gave it a try. I wanted to print the values for debugging but kept getting different executions each time.

One time, the cycle doesn't complete and the other time, it goes on to infinity. The debugging block also relates to the other **function(find_node_data)** I have to complete. So if I can figure what's wrong here, I can easily finish the find_node_data. I have commented a few things to see if it affects anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int node_id;
    int data; 
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
}node;



///*** DO NOT CHANGE ANY FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ***///
// Declare the tree modification functions below...
node* newNode(int data,int node_id){
    node* new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node)); 
    new_node->data = data; 
    new_node->node_id= node_id; 
    new_node->right= new_node->left=NULL;  
    return new_node;
}

node* insert_node(node* root, int node_id, int data) {
    if(root==NULL)
        return newNode(data,node_id);
    else{
        node* cur;
        if(node_id<root->node_id){
            cur=insert_node(root->left,data,node_id);
            root->left=cur;                
        }
        else if(node_id>root->node_id){
            cur=insert_node(root->right,data,node_id);
            root->right=cur;
        } 
    }
    return root;
}

// Find the node with node_id, and return its data
/*int find_node_data(node* root, int node_id) {
    node* current; 
    for( current = root->; current->next!=NULL; 
        current= current->next){ 
    if(current->data == data) return current; 
} 
return NULL; 
}
*/
int main() {
    /*
    Insert your test code here. Try inserting nodes then searching for them.

    When we grade, we will overwrite your main function with our own sequence of
    insertions and deletions to test your implementation. If you change the
    argument or return types of the binary tree functions, our grading code
    won't work!
    */
    int T,data,node_id;
    printf("Print yo cases");
    scanf("%d", &T);
    node* root = NULL;
    while(T-->0){
        printf("Type yo numnums no. %d:",T);
        scanf("%d %d",&data,&node_id);
        root=insert_node(root,data,node_id);
    }
    node *lol;
    node *king;
    for(lol=root;lol->left!=NULL;lol=lol->left){
        //for(king=root;king->right!=NULL;king=king->right){
        printf("executed!\n");  
        printf("%d ",lol->node_id);//,king->node_id);
        //}
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no language C/C++. C and C++ are distinct languages. And you should read [ask]. Also don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general.

Comment: Please show your input and output data, and indicate where it doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: `void print(node *np){
 if(np){
  print(np->left);
  printf("(%d, %d)", np->node_id, np->data);
  print(np->right);
 }
}` then call `print(root);` at main.

Comment: Also `node* insert_node(node* root, int node_id, int data) {` --> `node* insert_node(node* root, int data, int node_id) {`

Comment: When working with trees, or indeed almost any data structure, one of the first tools you should produce is a function that will print the data structure unambiguously.  You can then use that to check that things are working as you expect/intend.  That's what BluePixy suggested — it is absolutely the right way to go.  Keep the function around after you've 'finished'; it comes in handy when you next need to modify the code.  (Making the function `static inline` means you can keep it without getting complaints about it being unused.)

Comment: @Olaf The course introduces both C and C++. I understand there are different but similar at the same time. Just think of it as shorthand. I was wondering why is it wrong to cast the result of malloc.

Comment: It is deprecated and one of the differences between the two languages. That's **one** reason a course teaching both languages at the same time is a really bad idea. It typically is from some teachers who still think C++ is "C with classes" and did not move forward to modern C (C99, current standard is C11) and C++ (C++11, current standard C++14). If you use `0` or `NULL` as _null-pointer-constant_ in C++, you are taught strongly deprecated stuff (similar if you use `0` in C).

Comment: @Olaf I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the `node_data` you can use recursion to find the node.

```
node* find_node_data(node *root, int node_id) {    
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (root->node_id == node_id)
        return root;
    else {
        node *left = find_node_data(root->left, node_id);
        return left? left: find_node_data(root->right, node_id);
    }
}
```

And then get the data for the node e.g. get the data for node with node_id 42:

```
 printf("node data %d", find_node_data(root, 42)->data);
```

Full program below (I can't guarantee its correctness but maybe you can?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int node_id;
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;


///*** DO NOT CHANGE ANY FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ***///
// Declare the tree modification functions below...
node *newNode(int data, int node_id) {
    node *new_node = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->node_id = node_id;
    new_node->right = new_node->left = NULL;
    return new_node;
}

node *insert_node(node *root, int data, int node_id) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return newNode(data, node_id);
    else {
        node *cur;
        if (node_id < root->node_id) {
            cur = insert_node(root->left, data, node_id);
            root->left = cur;
        }
        else if (node_id > root->node_id) {
            cur = insert_node(root->right, data, node_id);
            root->right = cur;
        }
    }
    return root;
}

// Find the node with node_id, and return its data
/*
int find_node_data_old(node *root, int node_id) {
    node *current;
    for (current = root->; current->next != NULL;
         current = current->next) {
        if (current->data == data) return current;
    }
    return NULL;
}*/
node* find_node_data(node *root, int node_id) {

    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (root->node_id == node_id)
        return root;
    else {
        node *left = find_node_data(root->left, node_id);
        return left? left: find_node_data(root->right, node_id);
    }
}
void print(node *np) {
    if (np) {
        print(np->left);
        printf("(%d, %d)", np->node_id, np->data);
        print(np->right);
    }
}

int main() {
    /*
    Insert your test code here. Try inserting nodes then searching for them.

    When we grade, we will overwrite your main function with our own sequence of
    insertions and deletions to test your implementation. If you change the
    argument or return types of the binary tree functions, our grading code
    won't work!
    */
    int T, data, node_id;
    printf("Print yo cases");
    scanf("%d", &T);
    node *root = NULL;
    while (T-- > 0) {
        printf("Type yo numnums no. %d:", T);
        scanf("%d %d", &data, &node_id);
        root = insert_node(root, data, node_id);
    }
    node *lol;
    node *king;
    for (lol = root; lol->left != NULL; lol = lol->left) {
        //for(king=root;king->right!=NULL;king=king->right){
        printf("executed!\n");
        printf("%d ", lol->node_id);//,king->node_id);
        //}
    }
    print(root);
    printf("\n");
    printf("node data %d", find_node_data(root, 42)->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
Print yo cases3
Type yo numnums no. 2:22 42
Type yo numnums no. 1:21 41
Type yo numnums no. 0:20 40
executed!
42 executed!
41 (40, 20)(41, 21)(42, 22)
node data 22
```

You may also use Jonathan Leffler's improved recursion to find the node:

```
node *find_node_data2(node *root, int node_id) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else if (root->node_id == node_id)
         return root;
    else if (root->node_id > node_id)
        return find_node_data(root->left, node_id);
    else
        return find_node_data(root->right, node_id);
}
```

Both functions return the correct values as seen in the second test.

```
int main() {
    /*
    Insert your test code here. Try inserting nodes then searching for them.

    When we grade, we will overwrite your main function with our own sequence of
    insertions and deletions to test your implementation. If you change the
    argument or return types of the binary tree functions, our grading code
    won't work!
    */
    int T, data, node_id;
    printf("Print yo cases");
    scanf("%d", &T);
    node *root = NULL;
    while (T-- > 0) {
        printf("Type yo numnums no. %d:", T);
        scanf("%d %d", &data, &node_id);
        root = insert_node(root, data, node_id);
    }
    node *lol;
    node *king;
    for (lol = root; lol->left != NULL; lol = lol->left) {
        //for(king=root;king->right!=NULL;king=king->right){
        printf("executed!\n");
        printf("%d ", lol->node_id);//,king->node_id);
        //}
    }
    print(root);
    printf("\n");
    printf("node data %d\n", find_node_data(root, 42)->data);
    printf("node data find_node_data2 %d", find_node_data2(root, 42)->data);
    return 0;
}
```

Test 2

```
Print yo cases3
Type yo numnums no. 2:11 12
Type yo numnums no. 1:13 14
Type yo numnums no. 0:20 42
(12, 11)(14, 13)(42, 20)
node data 20
node data find_node_data2 20
```

Comment: You can do a better job in `find_node_data()` by using the ordered property of the tree: `node* find_node_data(node *root, int node_id) { if (root == NULL) return NULL; else if (root->node_id == node_id) return root; else if (root->node_id > node_id) return find_node_data(root->left, node_id); else return find_node_data(root->right, node_id); }`. This saves hunting down the left side of the tree when the node to be found is in the right side.  I took your code and made minimal changes; I'd probably reverse the tests `if (node_id < root->node_id)` to list what's being tested (`node_id`) first.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the interesting improvement. I included the improved function in my updated answer and a comparison that both functions return the same value. It could be interesting to analyze or compare the time for the recursions.

Comment: To reliably measure the performance difference, you'd probably need a reasonably large tree with maybe a hundred or so nodes in it.  One thing in favour of being able to measure the difference: suppose you have a 15-node perfectly balanced tree.  If you looked for the biggest value, your code would visit every other node first before finding the match; my code would visit just 4 nodes.  The disparity grows as the tree grows.  That's the extreme case, but your code does best (when searching for values in leaf nodes) looking for the smallest value, but my code performs equally as well then.